# Possibly French sci-fi cartoon about an organisation hunting down another organisation that turns out to be alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

I watched the cartoon in question around 2004-2005. It was about an organisation that was hunting down some sort of gang or criminal organisation that turns out to be alien in nature, and was preparing to invade Earth.

Here's what I can remember:

- The criminal/alien organisation in question disguised its members as humans. Their leader was an old man with a blonde, female assistant.
- The show ends with the heroes turning an alien super weapon against the invading alien fleet and destroying it.
- At one point the heroes capture the alien leader and his assistant.
- The reason I think it was French is because it had a similar art style to *Martin Mystery* and *Totally Spies*.
- I saw it on a Middle Eastern channel called MBC3, which mostly takes shows like this from Jetix and 4Kids.

Comment: Can you describe the alien super weapon a bit more? Like the approximate shape, size, and location?

Comment: [Roswell Conspiracies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_Conspiracies:_Aliens,_Myths_and_Legends)?

Comment: Either Roswell Conspiracies or Generator Rex...